# Error installing Drivers for Realtek Ethernet Controller (RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller)

Tags: drivers, ethernet, realtek

I am attempting to install the drivers for my RealTek Ethernet Controller (RTL8125) so I can use that ethernet port on my PC.  I have downloaded the drivers from the Realtek website, but when running the 'autorun.sh' file I receive the following output (with errors) in my terminal:

```
Check old driver and unload it.
Build the module and install
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.
DEPMOD 5.8.0-59-generic
load module r8125
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8125': Operation not permitted
Updating initramfs. Please wait.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-59-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p4
I: (UUID=d5c7989e-34c1-442f-8b29-99669f5a2585)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Completed.
```

I am still relatively new to Ubuntu, so any help would be appreciated.  I am not sure what the SSL Errors or the 'modeprobe: Error: could not insert 'r8125'' errors are referring to or how to fix them.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run the autorun.sh as sudo? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I did run it as sudo.

Comment: What is the response to: `sudo modprobe r8125` ?

Comment: @chili555 modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8125': Operation not permitted

Comment: Please give a link to the driver file you downloaded so that I may examine it.

Comment: Using the 2.5G ethernet option ( 9.005.06) from this page:  https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software

Comment: What is your kernel version? `uname -r` Also show: `lsmod | grep r8`

Comment: uname -r : 5.8.0-59-generic  |     lsmod | grep r8 gives does not show any output in my terminal

Comment: Please disable Secure Boot in the BIOS/EFI and try again starting at:`sudo ./autorun.sh`

Comment: I switched from 'Windows UEFI' Mode to 'Other OS' Mode in the Secure Boot menu in my BIOS and that seems to have fixed it.  Thanks!  Would you mind explaining this answer?