# Asus PN50-E1 and 18.04 LTS - No network adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, server

So, short and sweet:

- I got (for work purposes) a PN50-E1 with an AMD 4700U APU
- Everything works well if I install 20.04 desktop
- If I try to use 18.04 LTS (desktop or server), the ethernet network adapter is not recognized

We use 18.04 on all our managed machines, so going 20.04 isn't an option. But I would really like to stick to this hardware if possible.

How do I update the kernel used by the USB installer key `1804_netboot_unattended` to a version that will recognize the Network Interface?

EDIT: here is what I get when running `lspci -nnk | grep 200` from the shell of Ubuntu Server installer:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8125] (rev 05)
```

EDIT: after upgrading the kernel using `linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge`, everything works fine. I edited above to make the request more clear.

Comment: Let's start by identifying the adapter. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`

Comment: Done! The `-A3` flag is being rejected though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While several answers here appear to be duplicates, I don't believe any of them is exactly correct. I therefore propose a better answer.

With a working internet connection by tethering, USB ethernet or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms build-essential
```

Download the driver from the realtek website at: https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software Download the 2.5G Ethernet LINUX driver r8125 for kernel up to 5.6.

```
cd ~/Downloads/
tar -xvf r8125-9.006.04.tar.bz2 
cd r8125-9.006.04
sudo chmod +x autorun.sh
sudo ./autorun.sh
```

Reboot.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go. Is this something that I can do on the USB boot drive that we use for the unattended installation?

Comment: I suspect, with some complication, that you could. It is, however, beyond the scope of my limited networking knowledge. I suggest that you start a new question. I would try the driver installation *first* on a full installation to prove that it works without error.

Comment: Will do, thanks.

Comment: I am getting the same error as in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350472/error-installing-drivers-for-realtek-ethernet-controller-rtl8125-2-5gbe-control
Disabling secure boot has not fixed the problem.

Comment: From the quoted answer: " switched from 'Windows UEFI' Mode to 'Other OS' Mode in the Secure Boot menu in my BIOS and that seems to have fixed it." Is this an option you can try in your BIOS/EFI?

Comment: Doesn't look like said option is there. But funnily enough, it appears as the driver got installed, regardless of the error. I will try again and see where I stand.
Anyhow, thanks for the help. Much appreciated